# After upgrade from Flutter 2 to Flutter 3 on running automation, my app immediately crash after launch

Tags: flutter, mobile, automation

We try to run Automation with Webdriver.io, Appium and appium flutter driver.
After upgrade from Flutter 2 to Flutter 3 app is crash immediately after launch. It's happen on both Android and iOS (physical and simulator devices).
App release with Flutter 2 is work correctly.

Build command:

```
flutter build apk --debug --target=./test_driver/build.dart
```

Run command:

```
 npx wdio config/wdio.android.flutter.conf.js --spec tests/flutter_specs/app.test.spec.js
```

In Output get an error:

```
DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to response error: unknown error
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 500 due to unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
ERROR webdriver: unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
```

I cleaned npm node modules and package.lock and it didn't help.

My dependencies from package.json:

"dependencies":

```
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^6.1.16",
    "@wdio/cli": "^6.1.24",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework": "^6.1.23",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^7.5.3",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^6.1.24",
    "@wdio/sauce-service": "^6.1.16",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.1.23",
    "@wdio/sync": "^6.1.14",
    "appium": "^1.21.0",
    "appium-flutter-driver": "0.0.4",
    "appium-flutter-finder": "^0.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "webdriverio": "^6.1.24"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    "npm-bundle": "^3.0.3"
    },
    "bundledDependencies": [
    "@wdio/appium-service",
    "@wdio/cli",
    "@wdio/jasmine-framework",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter",
    "@wdio/local-runner",
    "@wdio/sauce-service",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter",
    "@wdio/sync",
    "babel-eslint",
    "node-fetch",
    "webdriverio"
    ]

 ### Update!!
```

We clone small flutter project with minimum dependencies: https://github.com/bitrise-dev/flutter-sample-app-hello-world
Before update to flutter 3 all works fine, but after it we get the same error mention before
Any help to solve the issue...

Comment: did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: Yes, i resolve this issue